# Update wx.BitmapButton?

Tags: wxpython

Edit: (little change -> 2nd problem)
I created a BitmapButton & a TextCtrl. The picture in this button shall change when a certain text is entered in TextCtrl. This works:

```
def create(self,event):
    self.textinput = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, pos=(100,20))
    self.picture = wx.Image("pics\\default.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.picturebutton = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel,-1,self.picture,pos=(100,50))
    self.textinput.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.changepic)

def changepic(self,event):
    if self.textinput.GetValue = 'test':
        self.picturebutton.Destroy()
        self.picture = wx.Image("pics\\new.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.picturebutton = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel,-1,self.picture,pos=(100,50))
    event.Skip()
```

1.) I hope there is another way instead of destroying & rebuilding this button. I tried

```
self.picturebutton.Refresh()
```

and

```
self.picturebutton.Update()
```

instead of

```
    self.picturebutton.Destroy()
    self.picturebutton=wx.BitmapButton(self.panel,-1,self.picture,pos=(100,50))
```

but nothing happened. What can I do?

2.) It looks like "changepic" is called *at first* and *then* my TextCtrl receives the char. Because when I enter "test", nothing happens until i press another key. So the picture changes when I enter e.g. "testa". But it shall change when "test" is in the TextCtrl. How can I solve this? Is there a TextCtrl-Event which *first* puts the char in the TextCtrl and *then* call a function?

Comment: I found one: EVT_TEXT ... but I couldn't find an answer for question #1 =(

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no need to recreate the control to change the bmp.
Refresh is what you need but rather then calling it on the control call it on the controls parent.

```
self.Refresh()
```

When using the EVT_TEXT event you can use event.String to get the contents of the control

Here your code with those changes

```
def create(self,event):
    self.textinput = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, pos=(100,20))
    self.picture = wx.Image("pics\\default.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.picturebutton = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel,-1,self.picture,pos=(100,50))
    self.textinput.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.changepic)

def changepic(self,event):
    if event.String = 'test':
        self.picture = wx.Image("pics\\new.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.picturebutton.SetBitmap(self.picture)
        self.Refresh()
    event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoriz's use of self.Refresh() was great, but I had to use

`self.picturebutton.SetBitmapLabel(self.picture)`

rather than

`self.picturebutton.SetBitmap(self.picture)`

to make it work. `SetBitmap` doesn't seem to be a valid wx.BitmapButton method. (Python 2.7)